# Display String [] in Recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to add the String[] array "favWalks" to a RecyclerView, but I'm not adding each element, only overwriting and displaying the last element.

I get the array from the Object calling the Getter then loop through it setting each element to the TextView but I'm only overwriting, is there a way to append to the RecyclerView?

I get the following response from a Retrofit call.

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5abeb626c2ef1603f406028e"
    },
    "email": "butlerpaul695@gmail.com",
    "completedWalks": [
        "Grand Canal Way"
    ],
    "favWalks": [
        "Grand Canal Way",
        "Sl? Na Finne - Sli Dhun na nGall",
        "Wicklow Way"
    ]
}
```

I have my UserModel with getters:

```
@SerializedName("email")
private String email;
@SerializedName("completedWalks")
private String[] completedWalks;
@SerializedName("favWalks")
private String[] favWalks;

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public String[] getCompletedWalks() {
    return completedWalks;
}

public String[] getFavWalks() {
    return favWalks;
}
```

My XML:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/user_chosen"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:minHeight="72dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="16dp">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:textColor="@color/input_login"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:contentDescription="Trail Name:"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/deleteWalk"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/white_border"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_delete"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Getting the response and calling the adapter:

```
List<User> userList = response.body();
recyclerView.setAdapter(new UserWalksAdapter(userList,R.layout.list_item_fav,getApplicationContext()));
```

And my adapter:

```
public class UserWalksAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserWalksAdapter.UserWalkHolder>
{
    private List<User> users;
    private int rowLayout;
    private Context context;

    public static class UserWalkHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        implements  View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener {
        LinearLayout usersLayout;
        TextView trailTitle;
        ImageButton delete;
        private TrailAdapter.ItemClickListener mListener;

        public UserWalkHolder(final View v)
        {
            super(v);
            usersLayout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.user_chosen);
            trailTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
            delete = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.deleteWalk);
            v.setClickable(true);
            v.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            v.setOnClickListener(this);
            v.setOnLongClickListener(this);
        }

        public void setClickListener(TrailAdapter.ItemClickListener listener) {
            this.mListener = listener;
        }

        @Override public void onClick(View view) {
            mListener.onClickItem(getLayoutPosition());
        }

        @Override public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            mListener.onLongClickItem(getLayoutPosition());
            return true;
        }
    }

    public interface ItemClickListener {
        void onClickItem(int pos);
        void onLongClickItem(int pos);
    }

    public UserWalksAdapter (List<User> users, int rowLayout, Context context)
    {
        this.users = users;
        this.rowLayout = rowLayout;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public UserWalksAdapter.UserWalkHolder onCreateViewHolder ( ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(rowLayout, parent, false);
        return new UserWalkHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(UserWalkHolder holder, int position)
    {
        //get array from User object
        String[] favWalks = users.get(position).getFavWalks();

        for (String s : favWalks)
        {
            Log.d("userWalksAdapter","TrailName:" + s);
            holder.trailTitle.setText(s);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return users.size();
    }
}
```

Thank you.

If its a work around, I can query my db to just return the array:

```
{
    "favWalks": [
        "Grand Canal Way",
        "Sl? Na Finne - Sli Dhun na nGall",
        "Wicklow Way"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass `string array` instead of `List<User>` to adapter Try this

```
List<User> userList = response.body();
String[] fav=userList.getFavWalks();
recyclerView.setAdapter(new UserWalksAdapter(fav,R.layout.list_item_fav,getApplicationContext()));
```

And change adapter constructor like this

```
public UserWalksAdapter (String[] fav, int rowLayout, Context context)
{
```

Comment: I can't call '.getFavWalks(); in the onResponse from Retrofit. Is it possible to call a class passing the object, then extract .getFavWalks() in that class and call the RecyclerView then? I added a response to my question that returns just the array if it is any help.

Comment: `List<User> userList = response.body();` to `User userList = response.body();`, try to return object instead of array, change in your network calls as well